# How to authenticate on Bluemix using SSO and REST?

Tags: ibm-cloud, single-sign-on

I'm using rest to authenticate users to Bluemix using an API key.  I would also like to implement username and password authentication.

```
def auth(self):
    self.log.debug('Authenticating to CloudFoundry')
    url = self.info['authorization_endpoint'] + '/oauth/token'
    headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
                'Accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
                'Authorization': 'Basic Y2Y6'
            }

    if self.api_auth:
        data = 'grant_type=password&username=apikey&password={}'.format(self.api_key)
    elif self.userpass_auth:
        data = 'grant_type=password&username={}&password={}'.format(self.username, self.password)
    else:
        raise ValueError()

    # send request ...
```

However, when I attempt to make the request using username and password, I receive the response:

```
{"error_description":"BMXLS0202E: You are using a federated user ID,
  please use one time code to login with option --sso.","error":"unauthorized"}
```

So I can send my users to the SSO web page to get a token, but what REST api do I need to make when they have the SSO token?  Or, do I use the same rest api as I am doing above, but instead provide a different parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to support username and password (I feel like I'm missing a piece of the puzzle here)?

I'd recommend using API tokens as a general good practice - some of the federated logins require a web-based token step which isn't great when working with integrations.

Comment: I agree with you.  I prefer API tokens and I started off with API token support in [my library](https://github.com/snowch/ibm-analytics-engine-python).  However, some users have requested that I support username/password as well :(

Comment: Well, you can support it but those with federated IDs will have to choose the API token route.  I really don't think you can work around this one :/